# PHP "Static" keyword is misleading its not retaining new value

Tags: php, static, increment, addition

ok im having a problem with the static keyword

**according to w3wchools.com below**

> Normally, when a function is completed/executed, all of its variables are deleted. However, sometimes we want a local variable NOT to be deleted. We need it for a further job.
>
> To do this, use the static keyword when you first declare the variable:

```
//w3school code below
function myTest() {
    static $x = 0;
    echo $x;
    $x++;
myTest();
myTest();
myTest();
}
```

now what this will do is basically count 0,1,2 with a ++ incremental operator. fine it does what there definition of static describes it does

now if i do the same thing basically in another way with my code below...the $x does not increment it just stays at 0.

```
//my code version below
function myTest() {
    static $x = 0;
    echo $x;
    $x + 1;
myTest();
myTest();
myTest();
}
```

these are basically doing the SAME thing in theory

w3schools version increments $x by 1 with ++ operator. increment means to add

my version adds 1 with + operator...and add means to add also

so is it safe to say that static only works for incremental operators
instead of basic math operators?

Comment: `$x + 1` doesn't assign back to `$x`.

Comment: `$x++` is equivalent to `$x = $x + 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `static` keyword. The code `$x+1` does not change the value of `$x` at all, so it never increments. `$x+=1` or `$x = $x + 1` would have the effect you wanted.

Comment: smh i should have known...youre absolutely correct thanks bro ! i love u guys on stack!